# How to limit the number of digits in a calculator program for the windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm having a hard time limiting the number of digits allowed on the text box. I have this code right here:

```
if (inputPanelTextBox.Text.Length >= 16)
```

I just don't know what to do under the if statement. What I want to happen is the same thing as the e.handled = true. When the text reaches 15 digits, don't do anything to it if the user attempts to add more digits.

Any help would be very helpful. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would do it handle the [OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.onkeydown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

inside of the handler, check the length of the string (as you have done), then set the [e.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.handled%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to true, this will stop the character from being added to the textbox.

Comment: I did that for the windows phone keyboard, but the problem is that the calculator I made is made up of buttons which enter the numbers. I put that piece of code I mentioned in the inputPanelTextBox textchanged event. So as the person presses down on the buttons and reaches 15 digits, what I want to happen is that the user can't add more digits.

Comment: instead of having your buttons change the textbox directly, have your buttons all call a method which will verify the current text length and only then add to it